# Can I change the default tab at /admin without losing access to /admin/tasks?

Tags: routes

Below I have changed the default tab at `/admin` to `/admin/index`, but now `/admin/tasks` is 403.  Even if I change `$items['admin/tasks']['access callback']` to `TRUE` I'm still denied access.

```
function hook_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/tasks']['page callback'] = 'system_admin_menu_block_page';
  $items['admin/tasks']['access arguments'] = $items['admin']['access arguments'];
  $items['admin/tasks']['file'] = $items['admin']['file'];
  $items['admin/tasks']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;

  $items['admin']['page callback'] = $items['admin/index']['page callback'];

  $items['admin/index']['type'] = MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK;
  unset($items['admin/index']['page callback']);
  unset($items['admin/index']['access arguments']);
  unset($items['admin/index']['file']);
}
```

How can I both restore access to `/admin/tasks` and set the default tab to `/admin/index`?

Resolution: The admin module was the problem.  It's enabled by default in my installation profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cleaned up some and prevents the admin module from botching /admin/tasks.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 *
 * Change default tab at /admin to that of the index rather than tasks.
 */
function hook_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/tasks']['page callback'] = 'system_admin_menu_block_page';
  $items['admin/tasks']['access arguments'] = $items['admin']['access arguments'];
  $items['admin/tasks']['file'] = $items['admin']['file'];
  $items['admin/tasks']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;

  $items['admin']['page callback'] = $items['admin/index']['page callback'];

  $items['admin/index']['type'] = MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK;
  unset($items['admin/index']['page callback']);

  unset($items['admin/index']['access arguments']);
  unset($items['admin/index']['file']);
  unset($items['admin']['menu_name']);
  // Prevent admin module from taking over in this case, but do not change
  // behavior.
  if (module_exists('admin')) {
    $items['admin/tasks']['access arguments'][] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please find this code to do this

```
function hook_menu_alter(&$items) {
$a_title = $items['admin']['title'];
$admin = $items['admin'];
$t_title = $items['admin/tasks']['title'];
$tasks = $items['admin/tasks'];
$i_title = $items['admin/index']['title'];
$index = $items['admin/index'];
$items['admin/tasks'] = $admin;
$items['admin/tasks']['title'] = $t_title;
$items['admin/tasks']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;
$items['admin'] = $index;
$items['admin']['title'] = $a_title;
unset($items['admin']['type']);
unset($items['admin/index']);
$items['admin/index'] = $tasks;
$items['admin/index']['title'] = $i_title;
}
```

Comment: There is still the same problem.  `/admin/tasks` denies access.

Comment: after change this code in your module, clear menu cache.

Comment: Aye, I tried that.  Does this code work for you?

Comment: Yes, used the same code, both tabs worked with this code.